# Import project from VM to IntelliJ

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I have 4 virtual machines set up on my computer using vagrant and I need to run the code in it but edit the code in my IntelliJ local IDE. how can I import the project from vm to IntelliJ?

Comment: Create shared file mounts? This question is really more appropriate for superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: did you create the project from the VM ? you need to move the project and be able to share it with your host so you can edit file in IntelliJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1. **Adding your code from vm to host**:
   You need to add project from remote server (In your case from vagrant VM). to know more look at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/create-new-project-add-remote-server.html)
2. **Sharing your host file to Vagrant VM**: 
   In this you need to add following lines to your vagrant file

   config.vm.synced_folder "/home/*user*/*folder_toshare*", "/home/*user*/*folder_toshare*"

and edit project form your local IDE and look for the changes in Vagrant VM.